# How to switch monitor screens using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, external-monitor

I have an external monitor attached to my laptop.
For switching between the screens, I need to move my mouse to one corner to switch to the other screen.

Is there any keyboard shortcut or another way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you correctly, you need to move a window to the second screen and backwards.

In this case the answer is  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> for the opposite.

You can find more shortcuts in the [Useful keyboard shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en) section of the official Ubuntu documentation.